# show() method removes the html element from dom instead of displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code,

HTML and php

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
  <div class="file-add-row" style="display:none;">Some content</div>
<?php } ?>
<div id="add-file-plus">Add File</div>
```

and the JS is

```
$('#add-file-plus').live('click', function () {
  if($('div.file-add-row:visible').length == 0) {
    $('div.file-add-row:hidden:first').show();
  } else {
    $('.file-add-row:hidden:first').removeAttr("style").insertAfter($('.file-add-row:visible:last'));           
    }
});
```

Now, my problem is, when I click the add button for the first time, the first 'file-add-row' div is displayed. But when I click the add button the second time, nothing happens on the page. Instead, it just completely removes that div from the dom.

I am just a beginner in jquery, so there might be things I overlooked. Anyone got any idea about what's going on ?

Comment: `<div class="file-add-row" style="display:none;">` When is `style="display:none;"` ever reversed?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
$('.file-add-row:visible:last')
```

Just after:

```
$('.file-add-row:hidden:first').removeAttr("style")
```

They both refer to the same object.  And if you try to insert an object after itself, it will end up removing itself from the DOM.

Change the JS to:

```
$('#add-file-plus').live('click', function () {
  if($('div.file-add-row:visible').length == 0) {
    $('div.file-add-row:hidden:first').show();
  } else {
    var last_visible = $('.file-add-row:visible:last')
    $('.file-add-row:hidden:first').removeAttr("style").insertAfter(last_visible);       
  }
});
```

Demo (Click on 'Add File'): 
https://jsfiddle.net/woxd2jbf/1/

Comment: Wow, that was such a simple solution. And it worked. Thanks a lot buddy. Saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without jQuery just plain JavaScript, it will work with divs just as it does with button, ul, and li. The details are commented within the source.

#### Key Methods

- [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)
- [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/F0Tcyha6aaKJ3tAfoVc1/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <!--This <li> is a template to clone-->
  <li class="row" style='display:none'>Some content</li>
  <!--This is the empty list to be populated with clones-->
  <ul id='list'>

  </ul>
  <!--This button will have an eventListener 
that will execute a function when it is clicked-->
  <button id="add">Add File</button>

  <script>
    /* Reference each element involved in process */
     // The button
    var add = document.getElementById('add');
     // The list
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
     // The first li
    var row = document.querySelector('.row:first-of-type');

    /* 
      1. Button will listen for a `click`
      2. Create a clone of the first li
      3. Add clone as the last child of list
      4. Set clone's display property to block 
      so it's visible
    */
    add.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
      list.appendChild(clone);
      clone.style.display = 'block';

    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I wanted a solution for jquery which I got. And Thanks a lot for your time. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're very welcome. I took the liberty of answering with JavaScript since you have the tag posted, but I understand all the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

**$('.file-add-row:hidden:first').removeAttr("style").insertAfter($('.file-add-       row:visible:last'));**, due to this line the issue is happening. because it first removes the **style** attribute which makes it visible so **$('.file-add-       row:visible:last')** is returning itself. refactor to store the visible el's reference like below:

```
$(function () {
    $('#add-file-plus').live('click', function () {
        if ($('div.file-add-row:visible').length == 0) {
            $('div.file-add-row:hidden:first').show();
        } else {
            var $el = $('.file-add-row:visible:last');
            $('.file-add-row:hidden:first').removeAttr("style").insertAfter($el);
        }
    });
})
```